# increase speed of access database on network drive

Tags: ms-access

I have a database that was required to be moved to a secure drive, ever since then my users have had increased slowness. I am looking for any suggestions that might be able to increase speed. So far we have removed some historical tables that we felt we could live without or archive that data elsewhere, and the next attempt will be to split the database, the only problem is scheduling a time for that and making sure all user have exited the database. We have managers that remotely access the database and forget to log out so we often cannot make some of the improvements we want. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple users in an Access database, and the database is on a network drive, you absolutely **must** switch to a front-end/back-end model.  Without doing so, not only are you increasing your chance of corruption (I hope you make a daily backup?), but you are guaranteed to see decreased speed for users.

What we have done historically is to tell users that at 5PM on Friday the DB is going down.  At 5PM, you copy the database to another folder and do your work there.  Any user who hasn't complied will lose their work.  This is also a good smack in the head so that they pay more attention next time.

Split your DB, and use a BAT file to roll out the front end.  Every user gets a copy of the front end on their C:\ drive.  **No one** runs a front end off the server.  This should increase speed, practically eliminate corruption, and allow future roll-outs to run smoothly.